# Cell returned from "cellforrowatindexpath" not rendering

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `cellforrowatindexpath` function that has both search functions and regular functions.

The cells are custom and have a couple of labels and an image.

Everything works perfectly, whether I search or not.

When I search a list of names, say "Mar" I get "Martin" and 5 blank cells. I am creating blank cells like this, i.e. cells to pad out the display, but that have no content.

```
    //If the requested cell is outside our search results, return blank
    if(indexpath.row < [resultsArray count]) {
        return [[PeepTableViewCell alloc] 
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                            reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
```

This works ok, but then when I backspace, and I get more results I just get blank cells.

Basically the cells have all the right properties, but its like they aren't rendering. I have added `[cell setNeedsDisplay];` but its not working.

**Is it something with the way I return blank cells to pad out search results?**

**Is there something I have to do to dispose of cells and recreate them once the number of results increases?**

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,

My first mistake was not returning a different value in `numberofrowsinsection` and `numberofsections` functions. These now check if its searching or not and return correct values.

This means I was setting a cell as nil and it was being reused.